# Cinder volumes fail to create when using a qcow2 image. Openstack/Packstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-cinder, openstack-glance

We are using a packstack installation of Openstack-Train with NFS as the backend driver for Cinder.

We are unable to create VMs using qcow2 images which were built from a cinder volume.

> Message Build of instance 8056996a-487c-4730-9ee0-f55dbf2fc320
> aborted: Volume 7506ee68-6c9f-427c-bb37-ab6213de1b8e did not finish
> being created even after we waited 80 seconds or 27 attempts. And its
> status is error. Code 500 Details Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line
> 2168, in _do_build_and_run_instance filter_properties, request_spec)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line
> 2478, in *build_and_run_instance bdms=block_device_mapping, tb=tb)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line
> 220, in **exit** self.force_reraise() File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196,
> in force_reraise six.reraise(self.type*, self.value, self.tb) File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2428,
> in _build_and_run_instance request_group_resource_providers_mapping)
> as resources: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in
> **enter** return self.gen.next() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2656,
> in _build_resources reason=e.format_message()) BuildAbortException:
> Build of instance 8056996a-487c-4730-9ee0-f55dbf2fc320 aborted: Volume
> 7506ee68-6c9f-427c-bb37-ab6213de1b8e did not finish being created even
> after we waited 80 seconds or 27 attempts. And its status is error.
> Created Aug. 25, 2021, 7:15 a.m.

Here are the key configurations made in the cinder.conf

```
[nfs]

nfs_shares_config = /etc/cinder/nfs_shares.txt

volume_driver = cinder.volume.drivers.nfs.NfsDriver

volume_backend_name = nfsbackend

nfs_mount_options = rw

default_volume_type=nfstype

enabled_backends=nfs

nfs_qcow2_volumes = true

nfs_snapshot_support = false
```

The strange part to this issue is that these same qcow2 images can be used when we rebuild the Openstack from scratch, however, any images created on the new setup still continues to have the same issue.

I am unable to post the entire cinder.conf or the log files due to size limitations. Please let me know if I can post it in some other way.

Comment: Could you use `raw` format image?

Comment: I seem to be hitting the same error with raw images too- Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "Raw_image", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: Build of instance 3a72d063-cf77-4452-92d9-9e16a1a78e8a aborted: Volume a9645a4f-eb35-40cb-9629-db69e7c53971 did not finish being created even after we waited 188 seconds or 61 attempts. And its status is creating.].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to fix this by setting the following parameters in the cinder.conf file (/etc/cinder/cinder.conf):

```
verify_glance_signatures = disabled
```

It turns out that Cinder has trouble verifying the metadata of the images created in Glance. Setting this parameter to disabled will resolve the error on any newer images you will create.

To fix the issue on an existing image use the command below:

```
openstack image unset --property signature_verified "id of the glance image"
```

To allow snapshots of NFS volumes, use the following parameter:

nas_secure_file_operations = False

Restart the cinder service:

```
- openstack-cinder-api
- openstack-cinder-scheduler
- openstack-cinder-volume
```

If you have a problem loading a RAW image, try the following parameters in the nova.conf file (/etc/nova/nova.conf):

```
block_device_allocate_retries=400

block_device_allocate_retries_interval=3
```

This will allow nova to create the large sized volumes.

Restart the Nova services:

```
- openstack-nova-compute
- openstack-nova-scheduler
- openstack-nova-conductor
```